# Can I decline a call in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like make an app for iOS (iPhone) for drivers and I would like to  know if it is possible to decline a call when my app is running... o whatever possibility.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is to broad and not clear. Let us know the specific issue you are facing in more descriptive manner.

Comment: @FarajFarook Huh? It's a very clear and narrow question. Is it possible, yes or no? No.

Comment: @FarajFarook How is the question not clear to you? It is a simple yes or no question like `rmaddy` has said I don't understand how that isn't clear. Unfortunately `dtorguet` it is not possible.

Comment: I'm not an IOS expert. I'm reviewing the questions. And at a glance, this question seems to have very less information.

Answer (score 2):

No, apps cannot affect phone calls in unjailbroken iOS devices. It'd be easily abused by malicious apps.

Answer (score 0):

Up un till iOS 8.2, the answer is pretty much a NO and there are certain basic things which will always provide an answer in case if a Later iOS version ever allows that.

**A)** Sandboxing  - As long as application are sandboxed they can only access data that they own (Exceptions are apple approved framework that allows you to access Camera, launch SMS composer, Email Composer, Access Address Book, Media Library etc.). Reading call logs, Auto sending SMS, Emails, Block calls using third party apps are a Big NO.

**B)** No third party application on iOS can run infinitely - First user can uninstall that app, second iOS can kill the application if it's running or if it's in background to free resources (Memory, Disk space).

Combining these two you can infer that any application that is intended to implement desired functionality in Problem statement here -  **"Decline a call when my app is running"** is not possible (in it's entirety)

Android (I've used) and Jailbroken devices can allow you to implement these features.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply .... the idea is to block an incoming call, if it is not possible ... is there any way to lower the volume of the device to zero?